# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <keras.layers.normalization.BatchNormalization object at 0x0000024B0C16B780>

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I don't know why BatchNormalization is giving the following error. Googled out but couldn't find any relevant answers

My code appears to be this:

[image: Code Snippet]

Comment: If you use keras, did you import it like that?
"  from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization  "

Answer (score 0):

How did you import "BatchNormalization" layer?
I had the same error and the solution was changing the way I was importing:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Dense, Conv2D, Flatten, Dropout, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization
```

I put the BatchNormalization with all the other layers, and it work in my case.

Hope it is useful.